# loading graph by ajax request inside a div tag of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-visualization

The graph I want to put is working here is the code.

graph.php

```
    <?php $mak="1";
    $sen="5";
    ?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pollution Mapper</title>
    <!-- Load jQuery -->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <!-- Load Google JSAPI -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
       google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
            var jsonData = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:"json.php" ,
                dataType: "json",
                data: { mak: <?php echo $mak; ?> , sen: <?php echo $sen; ?> },
                async: false,
                success: function(){
                    alert("asd");
                }
            }).responseText;

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable($.parseJSON(jsonData));



            var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(
                        document.getElementById('Chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data);
        }

    </script> 

</head>
<body>
<div id="Chart_div"></div>
</html>
```

The ajax request calling the above page is

```
$(document).on('click', '.jqf', function () {

    $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "./graph.php",
            data: { mak: $('.makid').attr('id') , sen: $(this).attr('name') },
            success: function(){
            }
        });
        return false; 

});
```

The function above is inside the index.html file. I want to load the graph in index.html file without reloading the file. How should I do it?.

Comment: You have a Javascript function in your PHP?

Comment: yes the javascript function is inside the php file.

Comment: what are you expecting back in the success from ./graph.php?

Comment: a graph, which is getting display on graph.php

Comment: Is 'Chart_div' located in your index.html?

Comment: no it is inside the graph.php page, I have edited my code have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is done, first I removed graph.php and inserted the function directly like Sam R said.

```
function loadChart(inMak, inSen) {

    google.load("visualization", "1", {
        packages: ["corechart"]
    });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./json.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                mak: inMak , sen: inSen
            },
            async: false,
            success: function () {
                alert("asd");
            }
        }).responseText;

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable($.parseJSON(jsonData));

        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(
        document.getElementById('Chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data);
    }
}

$(document).on('click', '.jqf', function () {
    loadChart($('.makid').attr('id'), $(this).attr('name'));
    return false;
});
```

Now the only change to do is this

Instead of

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {
        packages: ["corechart"]
    });
```

Write

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {
        packages: ["corechart"] , callback : drawChart
    });
```

and remove

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to put this script inside a function already on the page and not need to make a call to the server to set the two parameters you are passing in from JavaScript (through the AJAX data) anyway.

[This jsbin](http://jsbin.com/cibikohu/1/edit?js) shows roughly the idea.

Comment: I did it, but the page is getting reloaded and no content is shown

Comment: check this [link](http://riidl.org/mapper/). click on the mark and then click on the temprature image, the graph should be displayed below those images.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this?

Add a div to you index page:

```
<div id='chartHolder'></div>
```

in you success method on the ajax call:

```
$('#chartHolder').load('./graph.php');
```

or:

```
 $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "./graph.php",
            data: { mak: $('.makid').attr('id') , sen: $(this).attr('name') },
            success: function(data){
                $('#chartHolder').html(data);
            }
        });
        return false; 

});
```